# Trying to use jqplot with jquery mobile, marionette and requirejs

Tags: jquery-mobile, backbone.js, requirejs, jqplot, marionette

I am trying to use jqplot with Jquery mobile, marionette and requirejs. I have included all jqplot required CSS as well as script files in head tags, but when i am trying to plot a chart using below code

```
define([ 'jquery', 'plot' ], 
    function($) {
console.log("Success..Inside Offer Page Script.");
console.log("Plot..."+$.jqplot);
console.log("jquery..."+$);
$.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;
var s1 = [ 2, 6, 7, 10 ];
var ticks = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ];

plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [ s1 ], {
    seriesDefaults : {
        renderer : $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
        pointLabels : {
            show : true
        }
    },
    axes : {
        xaxis : {
            renderer : $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
            ticks : ticks
        }
    },
    highlighter : {
        show : false
    }
});
});
```

it gives me errors like

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function jqplot.barRenderer.js:41
(line 41: $.jqplot.BarRenderer.prototype = new $.jqplot.LineRenderer();)

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined jqplot.pointLabels.js:377
(line 377: $.jqplot.postSeriesInitHooks.push($.jqplot.PointLabels.init);)
```

The plot in my above code's define is

```
define([
  '../scripts/ext_libs/jquery.jqplot'
],
function () {
var plot;
require([
    '../scripts/ext_libs/jqplot.barRenderer',
    '../scripts/ext_libs/jqplot.pointLabels',
    '../scripts/ext_libs/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer',
  ],
function () {
    plot = $.jqplot;
});
return plot;
```

});

Can anyone please help me how can i solve these errors. Is their a problem using jqplot with requirejs?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can anyone else please help me solve this issue. Please.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not using marionette, but everything else works fine on my side. I have a jqplot module like this:

```
define([
    '../js/plugins/jqplot/jquery.jqplot'
  , 'css!../js/plugins/jqplot/jquery.jqplot'
  ],
  function () {
      var plot;
      require([
            '../js/plugins/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.barRenderer'
          , '../js/plugins/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.logAxisRenderer'
          , '../js/plugins/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer'
          , '../js/plugins/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.canvasAxisTickRenderer'
          , '../js/plugins/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.canvasTextRenderer'
          , '../js/plugins/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.pointLabels'
          , '../js/plugins/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.enhancedLegendRenderer'
          ],
      function () {
          plot = $.jqplot;
      });
      return plot;
  }
);
```

which I'm requiring requiring normally from my page script like this:

```
 require(["plot"], function (plot) {
   // do something here with plot or... $.jqplot
 };
```

You should be able to use `$.plot` right away, because once you require the module, jqplot will be available on `$`.

**EDIT:**
Try this:

```
define([ 'jquery', 'plot' ], 
    function($) {
        console.log("Success..Inside Offer Page Script.");
        console.log($);
        console.log($.jqplot);
        $.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;
        var s1 = [ 2, 6, 7, 10 ];
        var ticks = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ];

        plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [ s1 ], {
            seriesDefaults : {
                renderer : $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
                pointLabels : {
                    show : true
                }
            },
            axes : {
                xaxis : {
                    renderer : $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                    ticks : ticks
                }
            },
            highlighter : {
                show : false
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: @Nithalia: forgot to mention, I'm using the `css!` loader plugin found [here](https://github.com/guybedford/require-css)

Comment: Thanks for the reply @frequent. I have already referred your earlier post regarding the same topic, but still its not working. Can you please suggest what still i am doing wrong.

Comment: @Nithalia: what do you get when you `console.log(plot)` after your console? Also, although you are defining plot as a dependency, try without because it's also set on `$.plot`, so `define([jquery, plot], function($) {console.log($); console.log($.plot);}`

Comment: I tried logging jquery and plot instances i got this `Plot...undefined offer_page_script.js:9
jquery...function ( selector, context ) {
  // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
  return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );
 }` So i guess the main problem is that **Plot** is undefined. Can you help me with this?

Comment: you need to define "plot" in your requirejs config. `plot = path/to/plot-module.js"`. Then in your second snippet define.... see my edit

Comment: I have defined plot in my config like this `plot:'../scripts/utils/jqplot.module'` and rest i have edited same code as yours but still its giving me plot undefined. What should i do?

Comment: pardon... replace `$.plot` with `$.jqplot`. see above

Comment: Thanks..using `$.jqplot` gave me plot value in console. But the error still remains the same can you please help me solve those also?

Comment: Hello @frequent..Can you please help me solve my issue tomorrow its night over here. Please help me i ll update you with my code definitely

Comment: I have updated code of both classes can you please check and tell whats wrong. @frequent

Comment: Can you please help me @frequent

Answer (score 2):

Bit late to the game but.... above doesn't work because require is async to return, so able to return jqplot without any jqplot plugins loaded! async safe solution below

Nasty problem, as it's a chain of three dependencies

jquery is required for jqplot which is required for jqplot plugins, I have a simpler solution based on the same lines as the one above

first do your requirejs "main.js" config like so

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        "jquery": "path/to/jquery-1.10.2.min",

        // WORKAROUND : jQuery plugins + shims
        "jqplot.core": "path/to/jquery-jqplot-1.0.8.min",
        "jqplot": "jquery-jqplot-module-with-plugins-1.0.8"
    },
    shim: {
        "jqplot.core": {deps: ["jquery"]},
        "jqplot": {deps: ["jqplot.core"]}
    }
});
```

create a wrapper file module file called "jquery-jqplot-module-with-plugins-1.0.8.js", containing :

```
// wraps jquery jqplot plugin in define statement
define([
    "jquery",
    "path/to/jqplot.highlighter.min",
    "path/to/jqplot.cursor.min",
    "path/to/jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.min",
    "path/to/jqplot.canvasTextRenderer.min",
    "path/to/jqplot.canvasAxisLabelRenderer.min",
    "path/to/jqplot.enhancedLegendRenderer.min",
    "path/to/jqplot.pieRenderer.min",
    "path/to/jqplot.donutRenderer.min",
], function($) {
    var jqplot;
    jqplot = $.jqplot;
    return jqplot;
});
```

Then when ever you need jqplot with those plugins, simply call for "jqplot" which will load "jquery" then "jqplot.core" then all the jqplot modules, then finally return the jqplot object :)

```
require(["jquery", "jqplot"], function ($, $jqplot) {
    console.log("Success..Inside Require JS");
    console.log("Plot...", $.jqplot, $jqplot);
});
```

or

```
define(["jquery", "jqplot"], function ($, $jqplot) {
    console.log("Success..Inside Define JS");
    console.log("Plot...", $.jqplot, $jqplot);
});
```

tada! :)

ps jquery plugins are evil, no suggestion how to fix that situation, just a statement of fact

cheers

Ant

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `plot` is returned before `require(...)` initializes it. I used to have common solution and my `plot` was partly populated. I ended up with setting all jqplot plugins in `shim` and changed my `plot.js' accordingly, as was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976547/jqplot-not-working-with-requirejs-jquerymobile-marionette).

requirejs.config

```
shim: {
    'jqplot': ['jquery'],
    'lib/jquery/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.canvasTextRenderer': ['jqplot'],
    'lib/jquery/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.pieRenderer': ['jqplot'],
    'lib/jquery/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.barRenderer': ['jqplot'],
    'lib/jquery/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer': ['jqplot'],
    'lib/jquery/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.canvasAxisLabelRenderer': ['jqplot'],
    'lib/jquery/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.enhancedLegendRenderer': ['jqplot'],
    'lib/jquery/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.highlighter': ['jqplot'],
}
```

plot.js

```
define(['lib/jquery/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.canvasTextRenderer',
        'lib/jquery/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.pieRenderer',
        'lib/jquery/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.barRenderer',
        'lib/jquery/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer',
        'lib/jquery/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.canvasAxisLabelRenderer',
        'lib/jquery/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.enhancedLegendRenderer',
        'lib/jquery/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.highlighter'],
        function() {
    return $.jqplot;
});
```