# Jqplot not working with requirejs, jquerymobile, marionette

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, requirejs, jqplot, marionette

I am trying to use jqplot with Jquery mobile, marionette and requirejs. I have included all jqplot required CSS as well as script files in head tags, but when i am trying to plot a chart using below code

```
define([ 'plot' ], 
    function() {
console.log("Success..Inside Offer Page Script.");
console.log("Plot..."+$.jqplot);
$.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;
var s1 = [ 2, 6, 7, 10 ];
var ticks = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ];

plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [ s1 ], {
    seriesDefaults : {
        renderer : $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
        pointLabels : {
            show : true
        }
    },
    axes : {
        xaxis : {
            renderer : $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
            ticks : ticks
        }
    },
    highlighter : {
        show : false
    }
});
});
```

it gives me errors like

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function jqplot.barRenderer.js:41
(line 41: $.jqplot.BarRenderer.prototype = new $.jqplot.LineRenderer();)

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined jqplot.pointLabels.js:377
(line 377: $.jqplot.postSeriesInitHooks.push($.jqplot.PointLabels.init);)
```

The plot in my above code's define is

```
define([
  '../scripts/ext_libs/jquery.jqplot', 'jquery'
],
function () {
var plot;
require([
    '../scripts/ext_libs/jqplot.barRenderer',
    '../scripts/ext_libs/jqplot.pointLabels',
    '../scripts/ext_libs/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer',
  ],
function () {
    plot = $.jqplot;
});
return plot;
```

}
    );

Can anyone please help me how can i solve these errors?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: dont you have to put `.js` extensions at the end of the files.
i think its not able to find the code for barRenderer.

Comment: @Gyandeep Thanks for the reply but requirejs already assumes that the path given will contain a js file only. So its not required.

Comment: because when i run your code it runs fine for me using pure javascript. i think there is some problems with your include files.

Comment: yes i know but its important for me to do it using requirejs way @Gyandeep. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a global configuration object instead, take a look at this one : https://github.com/davidsulc/structuring-backbone-with-requirejs-and-marionette/blob/master/assets/js/require_main.js

It's from my new book on Marionette & RequireJS (https://leanpub.com/structuring-backbone-with-requirejs-and-marionette), and declares some jQuery plugins (e.g. jQuery UI).

Have you tried making your plot have jQuery as a dependency? It looks like that's the issue.

You'll probably need a config looking something like this:

```
requirejs.config({
  paths: {
    jquery: "path/to/jquery",
    jqplot: "path/to/jqplot",
    "jqplot.barRenderer": "path/to/jqplot.barRenderer",
    "jqplot.pointLabels": "path/to/jqplot.pointLabels",
    "jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer": "path/to/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer"
  },
  shim: {
    jqplot: ["jquery"],
    "jqplot.barRenderer": ["jqplot"],
    "jqplot.pointLabels": ["jqplot"],
    "jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer": ["jqplot"]
  }
});
```

This indicates that "jqplot" depends on jQuery, and the plugins depend on "jqplot". Then, you can have this in your code to define plot:

```
define(['jqplot.barRenderer', 'jqplot.pointLabels', 'jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer'],function () {
  return $.jqplot;
});
```

This will return the `jqplot` property when the plugins have been loaded. Your code can then be:

```
define([ 'plot' ], function() {
  console.log("Success..Inside Offer Page Script.");
  console.log("Plot..."+$.jqplot);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @David Sulc but i tried doing that. I added jquery dependency also but still same errors. Cna you please advice something else also? And one more question, is it compulsory to write the plot creating code in jquery's `document.ready`? Should the script run after the page is created completely?

Comment: I've edited my answer to reference an example global configuration you might want to try.I don't believe your issue has anything to do with `document.ready`, but the plotting code should most likely be in the view's `onShow` method to ensure the DOM elements are present.

Comment: I am doing that only @David Sulc, for requirejs I have a config file in which i give path for plot as this `plot:'../scripts/utils/jqplot.module',` but still errors :(

Comment: Your second code block doesn't require jQuery. I realize your first code block does require it, but that's too late. jQuery needs to be declared as a dependency in the module defining plot (per my code above).

Comment: Hello @David Sulc I have updated my code above please take a look and tell me how can i solve the errors.

Comment: I've modified my answer which was originally incorrect (it didn't require jquery proprerly...). Using the configuration as above should make your code work though.

Comment: Thanks for the help @David the updated answer worked for me, it's just I did on my own yesterday only. But seriously thanks for the help. Your code helped me alot. Thanks again.

Comment: I had the same kind of error and i had to declare the shim of Jqplot, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Nasty problem, as it's a chain of three dependencies

jquery is required for jqplot which is required for jqplot plugins, I have a simpler solution based on the same lines as the one above

first do your requirejs "main.js" config like so

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        "jquery": "path/to/jquery-1.10.2.min",

        // WORKAROUND : jQuery plugins + shims
        "jqplot.core": "path/to/jquery-jqplot-1.0.8.min",
        "jqplot": "jquery-jqplot-module-with-plugins-1.0.8"
    },
    shim: {
        "jqplot.core": {deps: ["jquery"]},
        "jqplot": {deps: ["jqplot.core"]}
    }
});
```

create a wrapper file module file called "jquery-jqplot-module-with-plugins-1.0.8.js", containing :

```
// wraps jquery jqplot plugin in define statement
define([
    "jquery",
    "path/to/jqplot.highlighter.min",
    "path/to/jqplot.cursor.min",
    "path/to/jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.min",
    "path/to/jqplot.canvasTextRenderer.min",
    "path/to/jqplot.canvasAxisLabelRenderer.min",
    "path/to/jqplot.enhancedLegendRenderer.min",
    "path/to/jqplot.pieRenderer.min",
    "path/to/jqplot.donutRenderer.min",
], function($) {
    var jqplot;
    jqplot = $.jqplot;
    return jqplot;
});
```

Then when ever you need jqplot with those plugins, simply call for "jqplot" which will load "jquery" then "jqplot.core" then all the jqplot modules, then finally return the jqplot object :)

```
require(["jquery", "jqplot"], function ($, $jqplot) {
    console.log("Success..Inside Require JS");
    console.log("Plot...", $.jqplot, $jqplot);
});
```

or

```
define(["jquery", "jqplot"], function ($, $jqplot) {
    console.log("Success..Inside Define JS");
    console.log("Plot...", $.jqplot, $jqplot);
});
```

tada! :)

ps jquery plugins are evil, no suggestion how to fix that situation, just a statement of fact

cheers

Ant